# JavaScript new Function() this binding

Tags: javascript, this

Bellow code example is normal function in strict mode and when we call this function browser console show undefined. This is normal.

```
"use strict";
function checkBinding() {
    console.log(this);
}
checkBinding();
```

But if we change code like bellow now console show Window object.

```js
"use strict";
var checkBinding = new Function("console.log(this)");
checkBinding();
```

What is going on there?

Comment: No If second exmaple also add use strict also this value show Window global object.

Comment: This is not duplicate question. Remove mark for duplicate.@CertainPerformance

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you mean. *functions created using the Function constructor don't inherit strict mode from their context, so must have an explicit `"use strict";` statement if you want them in strict mode.*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript

Comment: Can you send me Ecma Spesification link about this I don't find @CertainPerformance

Comment: @AndTheGodsMadeLove In MDN don't talk about functions created using the Function constructor

Comment: See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1 - `new Function` is described in the last bullet point. In short, `new Function` will always result in the code inside running in sloppy mode by default, unless the dynamically-created function has `'use strict'` in it

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks. But why there are don't do this default strict mode?

Comment: It might be because strict mode can cause errors instead of silent failures, and some (bad) scripts depend on those silent failures not throwing errors - so, strict mode has to be used deliberately

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have question this is interesting for me. new Function feature come from ES1 yeah?

Comment: But why new Function [[Environment]] always Global Lexical Environment? Is this for optimisaition?